# Use variable instead of keycode unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chararray

Okay so I'm trying to make a system that picks a random word then it turns that word into a char array. Then it will track if you type the characters. But the method that I'm trying to do hasn't been working. mainly because it won't let me use a variable name as a keycode. Is this a worthwhile problem, or should I abort mission and try something else.

```
string currentWord = wordArray[Random.Range(0, typingWords.Length)];
char[] wordAsArray = currentWord.ToCharArray();
Keycode currentLetter = wordAsArray[0];
if (Input.GetKey(currentLetter))
{
    Debug.Log("Test");
}
```

most of this works fine but what doesn't work the problem is the `if (Input.GetKey(currentLetter))`

is there something that can turn the word into a KeycodeArray or something like that or turn the specific character into keycode.

Does anybody know if this problem is solvable or will I have to use another method.

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't let me use a variable name"?  What *specific problem* are you observing?

Comment: You mean something like `KeyCode parsedKeyCode = (KeyCode) System.Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), "A") ;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is there something that can turn the word into a KeycodeArray or something like that or turn the specific character into keycode.`

There is not a built-in function for that. You can create a keycode array with each keycodes in it and use that to determine current letter. Like:

```
KeyCode[] letterCodes = new KeyCode[] {
    KeyCode.A, KeyCode.B, KeyCode.C, ... KeyCode.Z
};
KeyCode currentLetterCode = letterCodes[wordAsArray[0] - 'A'];
```

'A' is subtracted from it to get the index of the letter in the letterCodes array. This assumes that the word only contains uppercase letters.

Instead of that method i would use a different approach. I will write down a complete example of how i would do it with comments.

```
public class TypingGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text wordText;

    private string currentWord;
    private int currentIndex;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Pick a random word to type
        currentWord = GetRandomWord();
        // Display the word on screen
        wordText.text = currentWord;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Check if the current letter has been typed
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            KeyCode keyPressed = GetKeyPressed();
            if (keyPressed != KeyCode.None && keyPressed == GetNextKeyCode())
            {
                currentIndex++;
                if (currentIndex >= currentWord.Length)
                {
                    // The word has been completely typed
                    currentWord = GetRandomWord();
                    wordText.text = currentWord;
                    currentIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Update the display to show the next letter
                    wordText.text = currentWord.Substring(currentIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private string GetRandomWord()
    {
        // Replace this with your own word selection logic
        string[] words = { "cat", "dog", "bird", "fish" };
        return words[Random.Range(0, words.Length)];
    }

    private KeyCode GetNextKeyCode()
    {
        char nextChar = currentWord[currentIndex];
        KeyCode keyCode = (KeyCode)System.Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), nextChar.ToString().ToUpper());
        return keyCode;
    }

    private KeyCode GetKeyPressed()
    {
        foreach (KeyCode keyCode in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)))
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(keyCode))
            {
                return keyCode;
            }
        }
        return KeyCode.None;
    }
}
```

`GetNextKeyCode` method converts the next letter in the word to a KeyCode value by converting the letter to uppercase and using [System.Enum.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-7.0) to look up the corresponding KeyCode value.

`GetKeyPressed` method checks which key was pressed and returns the corresponding KeyCode value by looping over all possible KeyCode values and checking which one has been pressed using Input.GetKeyDown.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me I'm really new to c# and unity and this is perfect.